# Techniques for vocal to sound like tannoy announcement?

Tags: vocals

As the title says. I've got some cleanly recorded vocals and I'd like to get them to sound like a tannoy announcement. Anyone got some techniques to recommend for this?

Best,
Nicol

Comment: Actually, a bandpass and reverb does the trick quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use EQ to filter out the bass and some of the high end, and maybe boost the mids for a slightly harsh sound. Adding a small amount of distortion (or an amp simulator) might help to get the right tone.

Also, using a stereo delay is very important for a tannoy effect if you want it to sound like it's coming from multiple speakers in different positions. The sound would also reflect off any walls/buildings, so a delay serves both purposes. Maybe a tiny bit of reverb too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Mcdsp Futzbox or Audioease Speakerphone.

Answer (score 1):

The Techniques Tom.A mentioned work if you want to stay in the box. But there is another way to get a more realistic tannoy announcement. Just Record the vocals trough a loudspeaker. You can easily use "bad" recording devices like inbuilt microphones from handheld recorder.

Good Luck with experimenting!